# How to enable button in WPF when task is done

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a button, click it to start a task and disable the button, when the task is completed, I want to enable this button. Please give me any idea, concept or code to make it easy for me to understand.

my code is below:

In xaml:

```
<Button Name="myButton" Content="START" Click="ButtonStartClick" />
```

In xaml.cs:

```
 private void ButtonStartClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     RunTask();
     myButton.IsEnabled = false;
 }
```

In viewModel.cs:

```
     private void OnTaskCompleted(string result)
     {
          //how to enable myButton
     }
```

Comment: Show us the code for `RunTask`.  Shouldn't you be disabling the button **prior**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a first very naive approach, without MVVM

```
 private async void ButtonStartClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     myButton.IsEnabled = false;
     await RunTask();
     myButton.IsEnabled = true;
 }
```

where RunTask is declared like this:

```
 private async Task RunTask()
 {
     // await some other awaitable method(s)
 }
```

If you have a long running task that isn't awaitable, you may run it by `Task.Run` like this:

```
private async Task RunTask()
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // do somthing here
    });
}
```

Comment: This is the right answer seeing as he is using code behind for the click event. But I agree, there are other ways via binding to accomplish this; mostly used in the MVVM pattern.

Comment: Just to make it clear, using a view model doesn't mean you can't use async/await. The async RunTask method could as well reside in a view model.

Comment: @clemens thons for completing

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII yes the answer Is good using code behind only

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution in *MVVM* style. MainWindowViewModel.IsButtonEnabled defines if button may be clicked by user. ICommand.CanExecute defines if command will be fired on click.

Window.xaml:

```
<Window>
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Click me!" Command="{Binding ButtonCmd}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsButtonEnabled}" Width="100" Height="30"/>
    </Grid> 
</Window>
```

Window.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel(); 
    }
}
```

ViewModel.cs

```
class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private bool _isButtonEnabled = true;
    private ReaderWriterLockSlim _lock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        ButtonCmd = new Command(OnButtonClick, () => IsButtonEnabled);
    }

    public ICommand ButtonCmd { get; private set; }

    public bool IsButtonEnabled
    {
        get
        {
            _lock.EnterReadLock();
            bool result = _isButtonEnabled;
            _lock.ExitReadLock();
            return result;
        }
        set
        {
            _lock.EnterWriteLock();
            _isButtonEnabled = value;
            _lock.ExitWriteLock();
            OnPropertychanged(nameof(IsButtonEnabled));
        }
    }        

    private void OnButtonClick()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>{
            IsButtonEnabled = false;
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            IsButtonEnabled = true;
        });
    }       
    private void OnPropertychanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

Command.cs

```
class Command : ICommand
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    Action _cmd;
    Func<bool> _canExecute;


    public Command(Action cmd, Func<bool> canExecute)
    {
        _cmd = cmd;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute();
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _cmd();
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, commands are the intended way for full mvvm wpf approach. Depending on implementation requirements, locking might be unnecessary though (maybe when using `await` or so)

Comment: You should **await** that task you create. Also, its better to enable and disable the button **outside** the task in the main Ui thread else you run the risk of calling **OnPropertyChanged** from the wrong thread.  **Task.Delay()** is nicer to kittens too

Comment: No, I shouldn't. If you like and need async methods - go on, but they are not "use or die" stuff. Also there is no difference where to call OnPropertyChange because binding uses Dispatcher of the UI thread.

Comment: Well ok then.  -1